# inserted a rotation keyframe but need to move the starting position

Tags: animation, keyframes

so i created a rotation keyframe but its not positioned correctly, i would like to move this to a specific coordinate, but what happens is it "jumps". What I expected was it for it to rotate on wherever the object is. How can I keep the animation but move it entirely to another location?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if this isn't what you were asking, but to make a keyframe with location and rotation press I, then "LocRot"

Answer (score 0):

I would delete all location keyframes and keep only the rotation keyframes. Also, once you move it to the new location, make sure you add/replace the location keyframe. Pressing i on the keyboard, then clicking location.

The number of times I've moved an object and then hit the space bar to see the animation, without first adding/replacing the keyframe...

I hope this helps.